# Getting Number of Comments of Online news article with Python BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, screen-scraping, web-scraping

I'm using the following code:

```
import urllib
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import re 

comment_url = http://community.nytimes.com/comments/www.nytimes.com/2011/08/24/world/africa/24libya.html

response_new = urllib.urlopen(comment_url)
html_new = response.read()
soup_new = BeautifulSoup(html_new)
tags = soup_new.findAll('h3', {'class': 'share'})
for tag in tags:
    a = tag.renderContents()
    print a 

print "done!"
```

I am trying to obtain the number of comments readers have made on a certain New York Times Article by using the BeautifulSoup parser to look for information within certain tags. On a standard NYTimes article community page, the information is located like this:

```
<p>Share your thoughts.</p> 
</div> 
<div id="commentsWell"> 
<div id="readerComments"> 
<div class="header clearfix"> 
<h3 class="share">185
 Readers' Comments</h3>
```

However, when I run the code, I simply get the word "done!". It is apparent that my code isn't picking up any tags that I have specified. My question is - am I using BeautifulSoup incorrectly? If so, how would you suggest that I amend my code so as to get the desired information?

Thanks 
Sneha

Comment: If I correct the two errors in your code (the URL must be quoted, and `response` should be `response_new`) it works fine for me - outputs `189
 Readers' Comments
done!`

Comment: Thanks! It's the little things that fix it, is it not?

Comment: The confusing thing is that if you had those errors present in the code you were actually running, you wouldn't have seen the "done!" at all.  So maybe there was some other problem in the code you were actually testing...

Answer (score 1):

Use the `attrs` keyword parameter explicitly:

```
tags = soup_new.findAll('h3', attrs={'class': 'share'})
```

The call signature for `findAll` is:

```
soup_new.findAll(self, name=None, attrs={}, recursive=True, text=None, limit=None, **kwargs)
```

so when you omit `attrs=`, you are assigning the second argument, `{'class': 'share'}`, to `name` rather than `attrs`.